# Using "@" as a bash function name

Tags: bash, function

Is it possible to use the "@" symbol as a function name in a bash script? The following does not work:

```
function @() {
  echo hello
}
```

Comment: Works for me, under both recent and ancient versions of bash. What version of bash are you using?

Comment: @Gilles on`4.3.42(1)-release` (Arch Linux, package `4.3.042-4`), the function definition as given in the question doesn't give an error, but running `@` gives `@: command not found`. Ditto on `4.3.11(1)-release` (Ubuntu 14.04, bash package `4.3-7ubuntu1.5`). `export -f @` gives `export: @: not a function`.

Comment: @Gilles ah, it's due to `extglob`. Never mind.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 2:** While `@` is unproblematic in vanilla bash, it is used as a pattern grouping operator when the [extglob shell option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) is set, a simple `echo @()` can hang your shell under certain conditions. All the more reason to **not use `@` as an identifier`**.

**EDIT 1:** To clarify, it is not allowed per the definition of an identifier. I'm not recommending it. I'm just saying that for backwards compatibility, it is **possible** in bash to use `@` as an identifier.

```
@() { echo "$1 world"; }
@ hello
alias @="echo hello"
@ world
```

`@` is used as a special parameter (`$@`) and for arrays (`${arr[@]}`) but nowhere else. Bash won't stop you using it for identifiers like aliases and functions but not variable names.

Some people alias `@` to `sudo`, so they can execute commands as `@ apt-get install`.

The main reason why I would not use `@` as a shell identifier is that I'm so used to the [semantics of `@` in Makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8610814/201318) which silences commands without any side effects.

BTW: Works the same in zsh.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 4.3.11.  In fact, I had to nuke the shell process.

Comment: I forgot the semicolon. Why did you nuke the shell process?

Comment: It went almost totally unresponsive -- no prompt, no reaction on ^C,^D, or entering 'exit', 'quit'..

Still didn't seem to work for me, even escaping the @.  :-/

Comment: Weird, I just tested it in a 4.3.11 as well, works fine for me.

Comment: I got the same effect as  @JonCarter  on `4.3.11(1)-release` (Ubuntu 14.04, bash package `4.3-7ubuntu1.5`) and on `4.3.42(1)-release` (Arch Linux, package `4.3.042-4`),  after entering `@() { echo "$1 world"` and pressing enter, I get `{: command not found`.

Comment: @muru this is really strange, because `{` is not a shell builtin. I've tried on all the machines I could now: `bash --norc --noprofile -c '@() { echo hello world; }; @'` and it worked fine on all of them. @muru @JonCarter I'd really appreciate it if you could try that, maybe you have a shell option that influences this set in your bashrc? Does `type @` in a new shell maybe return something other than `type: @: not found`? @muru @JonCarter I'd really appreciate it if you could try that invocation, maybe you have a shell option that influences this set in your bashrc?`

Comment: Got it. It's due to `extglob`. And that's set if you use `bash-completion`. Indeed, with `shopt- s extglob`, a simple `echo @()` hangs the shell.

Answer (score 4):

From `man bash`

```
   name   A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, 
          and beginning with an  alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also 
          referred to as an identifier.

Shell functions are declared as follows:
          name () compound-command [redirection]
          function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
```

Comment: That's what the documentation says, but in fact bash is more liberal, and does accept a function called `@`.

Answer (score 3):

The naming of functions is quite similar to the allowed characters for alias:
From `man bash`:

> The characters /, $, `, and = and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an  alias  name.
>
> metacharacter
> One of the following: |  & ; ( ) < > space tab

So, except for:  / $ ` = |  & ; ( ) < > space tab

any other character should be valid for alias and function names.

However, the character `@` is also used for `@(pattern-list)` when extglob is active. By default extglob is active in interactive shells.

So, this should fail:

```
$ @(){ echo "hello"; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

However, this works:

```
$  bash -c '@(){ echo "hello"; }; @'
hello
```

And this should work as well:

```
$ shopt -u extglob                 ### keep this as an independent line.
$ @(){ echo "hello"; }             
$ @
hello
```

It is also possible to do this:

```
$ f(){ echo "yes"; }
$ alias @=f
$ @
yes
```

An alias is flexible in what symbols it accepts.